# How do i correctly use FormBuilderInterface in Symfony with Custom Types

Tags: php, symfony

I have 3 related Database tables (**inventory, sale, sale_details**) i would like to be able to make a form that can handle creating a Sale.

The problem is with my custom field "**InventoryType**" which should map correctly to an entity in the Database.

**NOTE**: *Inventory are stored uniquely on their serial number.*

I have created 3 custom field types, "**InventoryType, SaleDetailsType, SaleType**",

The **InventoryType** holds data equal to a Inventory table and (Inventory.php Entity)

The **SaleDetailsType** holds one **InventoryType**,

And the **SaleType** holds a collection of **SaleDetailsTypes**, account information and more.

I've tried with an **InventoryToSerialNumberTransformer** file to transform a Serial number into an inventory so that the InventoryType field only contains the serial number.

```php
// src/Form/Type/InventoryType.php
$builder->add('serialNumber', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Serialnumber'])
```

```php
// src/Form/Type/SaleDetailsType.php
$builder->add('Inventory', InventoryType::class, ['label' => 'Inventory item']);
```

```php
// src/Form/Type/SaleType.php
$builder->add('account', EntityType::class, [ 'class' => Account::class ])
    ->add('shop', EntityType::class, [ 'shop' => Shop::class ])
    ->add('saledetails', CollectionType::class, [ 'entry_type' => SaleDetailsType::class, 
                                                  'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
                                                  'allow_add' => true ])
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Create Sale!']);
```

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

{{ form_row(form.account) }}
{{ form_row(form.shop) }}

<h3>Saledetails</h3>
<ul class="saledetails">
    {% for detail in form.saledetails %}
        {% for inventory in detail %}
            <li> {{ form_row(inventory.serialNumber) }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{{ form_row(form.save) }}

{{ form_row(form._token) }}
```

**Expected behavior:**

When adding list items via clientside JavaScript that is identical to the format that symfony uses (this is already done and works perfectly) the "inventory" should be correctly inserted just from the serial number alone.

Comment: sooo ...  you get a serial number, but the `inventory` property in `SaleDetails` is a many-to-one relation to an `Inventory`, is that correct?

Comment: Because this Database requires that "inventory" items are unique, its a one to one relationship.

```php
/**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Inventory", inversedBy="saleDetails", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $inventory;
```

But i think it would be a many-to-one were it not unique, like say (non-unique products.)

Comment: okay, so every inventory only ever appears once. and the form your currently developing is not meant to create really new inventory objects but just ... assign them, but it should be done via entering a serial number? if that's the case, you probably have to add some form of post-processing and pre-processing and get an entity-manager in there. Which is probably what your transformer does. care to show it and tell us, what's the problem with that approach?